# Is there a correlating version of ICU for php installations?

Tags: php, yii2, intl

I was wondering if there is a correlating version of ICU (for intl) for php installations. I am using Yii framework and want to upgrade to version 2.0.7 which requires ICU version 49 or higher. My dev machine has ICU data version 53.1 and my production server have ICU version 4.2.1. A technician from the hosting company said, other things:

> "I have researched the software package further and verified that the
>   php version currently installed on the server (5.6) has the latest
>   version of "libicu.x86_64".  Newer versions of this package are
>   available from red hat directly but will require the removal and
>   manual install of the software package(not recomended and will not be
>   supported in the future)".

Does a certain php installation come with a certain ICU version? Would upgrading to, say, php 5.6.18 fix this without having to upgrade ICU separately?

Comment: Exactly how would you upgrade to php 5.6.18? It's a RHEL 6 machine?

Comment: I am not much of a sysadmin at all, I have sysadmins on contract that perform software upgrades for me.